# Problems with SSRS browser

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

When I try to go to my `SSRS` reports via browser (`http://srv-dbmssqlprd0/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx`), it doesn't open:
[image]

Than I went to Visual Studio 2008 and tried to run the report, it works. And than I've tried to deploy any of the reports, it prompts the following: [image]

I've tried to enter my username and login, it doesn't accept it.

This problem occurs from time to time. Environment and connection to server was done by another person (who is unavailable from now on).

How can I fix this problem, so that the browser opens with all my developed reports?

I'm absolutely new to setting an anvironment for `SSRS`, so please ask me questions similar to, "go there and put screen of this configurations", "show this" and so on.

Please, I need to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

> When I try to go to my SSRS reports via browser
>   (http://srv-dbmssqlprd0/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx), it doesn't open:

HTTP 500 Error code is an internal server error.
To see the real error you have 2 options:

- Log on the report server and go to http://localhost/reports
- Disable the "Show friendly HTTP error messages" textbox in Internet Options
  [image]

> And than I've tried to deploy any of the reports, it prompts
>   the following:

The credentials are prompted because you can't be authenticated on the Report Server with your current Windows Credentials.
This can be the expected behavior if you want to use another account than the one you are logged in to deploy the reports.
If it is not the case, just give the appropriate rights to your Windows account on the report server.

Make sure the account you use to deploy the report is associated to one of the following default Roles:

- Content Manager
- My Reports
- Publisher

If this user is associated to a custom role, ensure this role has the *Manage Reports* task

Comment: It didn't help, even though your instructions seems to be reasonable. I've simply restarted reporting server and problem disspeared itself. Thanks

Comment: @SherzodMuminov Happy to hear that, the problem is that if you don't find the root of the issue, it could happen again. Also, you should still disable the "Show friendly HTTP error messages" option. I cannot see a good reason to have this option enabled on a development computer.

Comment: I've followed all your instructions and greatly appreciate that. If the problem returns, I will dig deeper